# Howto create dynamic pages with middleman 3.0.9

Tags: ruby, middleman

I'm fiddling with middleman 3.0.9 for some time now, trying to create some dynamic output that I need.

Older versions had the "dynamic pages" feature. 3.0.9 does not seem to have something similar. I do not find anything in the docs, nor in the net at the moment.

I simply want the endpoint '/foo' dto do some processing and return some custom data with every request.

How can I achive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Dynamic Pages](http://middlemanapp.com/dynamic-pages/) feature is still provided by Middleman. Though its purpose is to dynamically create pages at build time (`middleman build`). The *Dynamic Pages* feature is **not** helping you to process data and serve dynamic content.

Middleman is a static site builder, and is not supposed to serve dynamic content.

If you need data processing done on each request hava a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/).

Comment: Thx for the answer cutemachine. I did it, using a helper method defined in a custom module. I simply needed some dynamic JSON results based on a query in a POST request. Rendering the helper's output in my ERB did the trick.